# ¿Cómo resolver org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class GenericModelRepository<T>
{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session session = null;

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    //@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
    public List<T> fetchAll(Class<T> classType)
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<T> registers = null;
        try
        {
            //session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();//.createCriteria(classType).list();
            CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery= criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classType);
            Root<T> entities = criteriaQuery.from(classType);
            Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.gt(entities.<Integer> get("sst_Id"), 0);
            criteriaQuery.select(entities).where(p);//criteriaBuilder.gt(entities.get("stt_Id"), 0));
            Query<T> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
            registers = query.getResultList();
            //registers = session.createCriteria(classType).list();
        }catch(HibernateException he)
        {
            System.out.println(he.getStackTrace());
        }/*finally
        {
            session.close();
        }*/
        return registers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes inyectar el EntityManagerFactory. Si no, va a mandar nulo.

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName= "myPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Comment: Me podria dar un ejemplo de como?

Comment: Si. Edité la respuesta. Ahí está un ejemplo. Se puede hacer de otras formas.